# How can I use lazyload in Angular4?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I try to do

**{ path: 'options', loadChildren: 'app/options/options.module#OptionsModule'}**

every file module,html,js load complete

I can route normaly

but I click link route in loadChildren not thing change

I use **hashbang(#)** in root route

I can't not write this **RouterModule.forChild(routes,{ useHash: true })**

if you not use lazy load Angular will load all of page and component for 1 route

**Question?**
1. How necessary to set 
ChildRouter Hashbang like this

RouterModule.forChild(routes)

Because RootRouter use hashbang(#) like this

RouterModule.forRoot(routes,{ useHash: true }) ?

2.you can show me code Angular4.X in Lazyload Route loadChildren ?

------------------------ Please Help Me -----------------------------

I use this : https://github.com/varishero/laravel5.4-angular4-ts2

Comment: the question is not clear!! you need to provide more information
by default if you using angular-cli and angular modules with loadChildren and define mosules routes in module with RouterModule.forChild it should work
please add your code or more information

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a module named TestModule in test.module.ts locates at app/test/, in routing to load it:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'test', loadChildren: 'app/test/test.module#TestModule'},
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear enough, but if you want to lazy load module,
then refer following example for lazy load ordersModule

your app.route.ts will be

```
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [{
    path: 'orders',
    loadChildren: 'app/components/orders/orders.module#OrdersModule'
}]

@NgModule({
    imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })
],
exports: [
    RouterModule
],
declarations: []
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

and orders.routing.module.ts will be

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { OrderDetailsComponent } from './order-details/order-details.component';
const routes: Routes = [{
   path: 'orderDetails',
   component: OrderDetailsComponent
}];
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class OrdersRoutingModule { }
```

Now you can access orderdetailscomponet as localhost:4200/#/orders/orderDetails